# Gatling: define message rate in minutes (JMS scenario)

Tags: jms, gatling

I'm performing a load tests against IBM MQ and would like to have 10 msgs./users being submitted in 10 minutes (just a as a proof of concept).
I'm injecting the respective load like this:

```
scn_message_ZIP_DP102.inject(rampUsers(10) over(10 minutes)).protocols(jmsConfigMQ1)
```

But when checking the logs I'm seeing the applicaiton is being flooded with messages. I'd expect to have just 10 messages being submitted in a timeframe of 10 minutes.

Comment: How your scenario looks? Maybe there is something wrong?

Comment: val scnMessageID14 = scenario("Load testing InboundQueue on MQ-HOST-1 with MessageID14").during(48 hours) {
    exec(jms("F&F testing with MessageID 14").send
      .queue("MESSAGES.QUEUE")
      .textMessage(message14)
    )
  }

Comment: thanks for your feedback, @MateuszGruszczynski - see above, this is my scenario - nothing fancy here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well we have an answer - in 10 minutes you start 10 users and every of them is sending message after message in a 48 hour loop, so instead of 10 messages you probably have hundreds of millions of them. Remove `during` loop and it should be fine fe.:

```
val scnMessageID14 = scenario("Load testing InboundQueue on MQ-HOST-1 with MessageID14")
  .exec(
    jms("F&F testing with MessageID 14")
      .send
      .queue("MESSAGES.QUEUE")
      .textMessage(message14) 
  )
```

Comment: ok, but I'd like to have my test running for 48 hours, i. e. during the given duration of 48h I want to have 10 messages/minute respectively.

Comment: Then the best way to do it to have scenario with just 1 message and then injection strategy that injects 10 users per minute (1/6 of user per second) for 48 hours fe: `scnMessageID14.inject(constantUsersPerSec(1d/6).during(48 hours))`